# Do I need to secure further my delete form

Tags: php, security

I have a site that requires admin access to perform some functions - one of which is to delete rows in a table.
So I have secured the pages by using session logins as standard, and I can see .htaccess file in the root folder of the site.

In order to perform the delete, the admin user will click a delete button and while the Delete query cannot be seen on the page, the table name CAN be seen in the hidden value, because based on which delete button is clicked, different tables will be cleared using standard mysqli_query.

```
<form method='POST' action='deleteData.php' target="_blank">
<input type='hidden' value="table_name_one" name='tbl'>                             
<input type='submit' value='Delete'>
</form>

<form method='POST' action='deleteData.php' target="_blank">
<input type='hidden' value="table_name_two" name='tbl'>                             
<input type='submit' value='Delete'>
</form>
```

The deleteData.php only deletes once the user enters a further confirmation key

```
<?php
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (isset($_POST['delete']))){
    if ($_POST['delete_conf'] === 'DELETE') {
         //connect
         //mysqli_query DELETE FROM table_name

         ...
?>
     <body>
        <p>Confirm key:
        <input type="text" name="delete_conf" id="delete" value="" /> 
        <input type='hidden' value="<?php if (!empty($tbl_name)) { echo $tbl_name; } ?>" name='tbl'>
        </p>
<input type='submit' name="delete" value='DELETE!'>
```

So I'm wondering, with the login/htaccess security, do I need to go further in securing the page ? How else can this be compromised ?

I can see that using dev tools, considering the table name is within the form submit buttons, and can be changed IF the user were to find out the other table names.

Comment: From what little code you provided, I would only assume that it can easily be hacked by simply changing the table name in the hidden input.

Comment: yeh no use providing the whole code - its more about is the process ok, is htaccess + login ok

Comment: For the generic question "is htaccess + login ok?", that would depend on if your login system is vulnerable in some way. I don't see anything in that code that validates the login or even checks that the logged in user is valid. So it is not possible to reliably answer the question. The code *posted* is not secure simply because what was posted doesn't cover *anything* from that question.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Make sure to use prepared statements with either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
(2) Check the `tbl` value against a list of valid values, so that the user cannot just change it to whatever table they want.

```
if(in_array($_POST['tbl'], array('table_name_one', 'table_name_two')))
{
   ....
}
else
{
  echo 'stop trying to hack';
}
```